# modifying the small device version dashboard

Tags: qlikview

From your access point you can load the "small device version". When I click on that it brings me to a dashboard that has has each of the tabs as rows and each individual component listed for that row.

Is there a way to modify this dashboard? For example, put what time frame they have selected on the dashboard so they can see it at all times (instead of having to click on the month and year components), or just start on a particular module that people are there to look at 90 percent of the time?

Answer (score 0):

I might not fully understand your question but if I do then have you tried adding a current sections object somewhere. If that object is to large you could also try to add a text object and use the GetSelections functions.

Comment: My work blocks imgur so it is difficult to post a picture. I don't think this answer is quite what I am looking for, if you go into your access point and click on "small device version" for any of your qlikview projects, it will bring you to a dashboard that lists out the objects based on tab. I was wondering if there was a way to modify that dashboard in a similar way qlikview desktop modifies the desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no easy "built-in" method to modify the appearance of the "small device view" version of a QlikView document.

The only way to do this is to directly modify the webserver's source files (i.e. HTML/CSS/JS) on your QlikView server. These may be found for QV11 in the following folder (bear in mind that this can depend on your OS's architecture and the version of QlikView server you have installed).

`/Program Files/QlikView/Server/QlikViewClients/QlikViewAjax/mobile/`

Answer (score 0):

I found out there is not really a way to modify the main mobile dashboard but you can put all of the content you want into a container and have the iframe go to the singleobject.htm version such as:

```
http://qlikview/RAUlOUL/singleobject.htm?document=test.qvw&object=CT07
```

This is a made up URL so it won't work but if it did you would see just the container fitting the maximum size of the screen.